# django please look at the Index Error i am getting institutes ip admin module for edit and save ip address and validation

Tags: django

I get this error:

> Exception Type: IndexError at /institutes_admin/ Exception Value: list
>   index out of range

Here are some details about the error:

Environment:

> Request Method: GET Request URL:
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/institutes_admin/
>   Django Version: 1.1.1 Python Version:
>   2.6.5 Installed Applications: ['django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.admin', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
>   'django.contrib.markup', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.sites', 
>   'django.contrib.comments', 
>   'mysite.registration', 
>   'mysite.profiles',  'mysite.epw', 
>   'mysite.remember_me', 
>   'mysite.avatar', 
>   'mysite.django_documents', 
>   'mysite.inlines',  'mysite.blog', 
>   'mysite.forum',  'tagging'] Installed
>   Middleware:
>   ('django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
>   'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
>   'mysite.remember_me.views.AutoLogout')
>
> Traceback: File
>   "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in get_response
>     92.                 response = callback(request, *callback_args,
>   **callback_kwargs) File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/utils/decorators.py"
>   in _wrapped_view
>     48.                 response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   File
>   "/home/karthik/Desktop/mysite/../mysite/epw/admin_views.py"
>   in institutional_ip_admin
>     614.        arranged_list = arrange_ips(chk_exist_obj) File
>   "/home/karthik/Desktop/mysite/../mysite/epw/admin_views.py"
>   in arrange_ips
>     582.                total_value += (map_range(institute_obj, index), )
>   File
>   "/home/karthik/Desktop/mysite/../mysite/epw/admin_views.py"
>   in map_range
>     558.        ip_value = ip_list_read(institute_obj,
>   list_value, index) File
>   "/home/karthik/Desktop/mysite/../mysite/epw/admin_views.py"
>   in ip_list_read
>     548.        ip_value.append(str(object_persistance(getattr(institute_obj,
>   list_value + str(i)))[index-1]))
>
> Exception Type: IndexError at
>   /institutes_admin/ Exception Value:
>   list index out of range

module I am working on:

```
def institutional_ip_admin(request, form_class = Institutional_Subscription_Form,template_name
    = "institutional_subscription.html"):   

    current_user = request.user
    super_user, admin_user, dict_user = chk_admin_user(current_user)

    if (super_user and admin_user) or (not super_user):       
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/admin_access/")

    update_user_id = request.session['update_user_id'] 
    result_of_update, result_of_category, result_of_cover, result_of_latest, result_of_block, result_of_footer, result_of_research = common_blocks()
    ip_type = request.POST.get('ip_type')
    update_user = User.objects.get(id = update_user_id)
    chk_exist_obj = institutional_subscription.objects.filter(user__id=update_user_id).order_by('-id')
    redirect_location = '/success/update_subscription/'
    arranged_list = []

    if chk_exist_obj:
        chk_exist_obj = chk_exist_obj[0]
        ip_type = chk_exist_obj.ip_type
        arranged_list = arrange_ips(chk_exist_obj)
                        print arranged_list

    if request.method == "POST":

        form = form_class(data=request.POST)

        if request.POST.get('ip_type') == 'edit':
            data_dict = map_ip_attrs(request.POST)
            result_dict = ip_seperate(data_dict, chk_exist_obj.ip_type)
            chk_exist_obj.from1 = str(result_dict['from1'])
            chk_exist_obj.from2 = str(result_dict['from2'])
            chk_exist_obj.from3 = str(result_dict['from3'])
            chk_exist_obj.from4 = str(result_dict['from4'])
            chk_exist_obj.to1 = str(result_dict['to1'])
            chk_exist_obj.to2 = str(result_dict['to2'])
            chk_exist_obj.to3 = str(result_dict['to3'])
            chk_exist_obj.to4 = str(result_dict['to4'])
            chk_exist_obj.access_limit = request.POST.get('access_limit')
            chk_exist_obj.save()

            new_id = chk_exist_obj.id
            old_user = chk_exist_obj.user
            delete_old_records = institutional_subscription.objects.filter(user= old_user).exclude(id = new_id).delete()
            return render_to_response('successful.html', {'user' : current_user, 'editsuccess':'Ips are updated successfully','result_of_update' : result_of_update, 'result_of_category' : result_of_category, 'result_of_cover' : result_of_cover, 'result_of_latest':result_of_latest, 'result_of_block' : result_of_block, 'result_of_footer':result_of_footer,  'result_of_research' : result_of_research, })

        elif form.is_valid():
            data_dict = form.cleaned_data
            ip_type = request.POST.get('ip_type')
            result_dict = ip_seperate(data_dict, ip_type)
            ip_obj = institutional_subscription(

                        user = update_user, 

                        from1 = str(result_dict['from1']), 

                        from2 = str(result_dict['from2']), 

                        from3 = str(result_dict['from3']), 

                        from4 = str(result_dict['from4']),

                        to1 = str(result_dict['to1']),

                        to2 = str(result_dict['to2']),

                        to3 = str(result_dict['to3']),

                        to4 = str(result_dict['to4']),

                        access_limit = request.POST.get('access_limit'),

                        ip_type = ip_type
            )

            ip_obj.save()
            new_id = ip_obj.id
            old_user = update_user  
            delete_old_records = institutional_subscription.objects.filter(user = old_user).exclude(id = new_id).delete()
            return render_to_response('successful.html', {'user' : current_user, 'editsuccess':'Ips are updated successfully','result_of_update' : result_of_update, 'result_of_category' : result_of_category, 'result_of_cover' : result_of_cover, 'result_of_latest':result_of_latest, 'result_of_block' : result_of_block, 'result_of_footer':result_of_footer,  'result_of_research' : result_of_research, })  

    else:
        form = form_class()

    pageinfo = "SubscriptionInstituteIpRange"    
    return render_to_response(template_name, {'user' : current_user, 'form' : form, 'result_of_category':result_of_category, 'result_of_update' : result_of_update, 'result_of_category' : result_of_category, 'result_of_cover' : result_of_cover, 'result_of_latest':result_of_latest, 'result_of_block' : result_of_block, 'result_of_footer':result_of_footer, 'result_of_research' : result_of_research, 'chk_exist_obj' : chk_exist_obj, 'arranged_list' : arranged_list, 'super_user' : super_user, 'redirect_location' : redirect_location})
```

Comment: Yep, that's a nice error, thanks for sharing.

Comment: It would be useful if you can explain what you were trying to achieve and perhaps show the block of code that's causing the problem.

Comment: partially my fault I suppose. I said Blockquote when I meant use the Code icon.

Comment: @ravi your code was indented bad. I just edited it. Please tell me if the indentation is correct now. If you post a code indented wrong, then it is difficult to understand what should it do, and where the error lies.

Comment: Also please give a better title to your post. The title should summarize your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen your error (as requested), and it's not pretty. However, I can offer you two comments:

1. You should format it better to make it clearer. For the multi-line trackback, you'll want to format it using blockquotes. select the text, then click on the IOIO icon (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd>).
   [image: code icon]
    « click that after selecting your pasted code!!
2. Your problem seems to be in your `ip_list_read` function in `admin_view.py` line `548`. Perhaps `index-1` is larger than the actual size of the list returned by `object_persistence(...)`?

Of course, this is all guesswork as I don't know what the rest of the function look like, or what you're trying to achieve.

#### Update

Somewhere within that pile of code you have something that looks like

```
if chk_exist_obj: 
    chk_exist_obj = chk_exist_obj[0] 
    ip_type = chk_exist_obj.ip_type 
    arranged_list = arrange_ips(chk_exist_obj) 
    print arranged_list
```

Your `arrange_ips()` function is the one that's causing the problem. What exactly does it do? Based on the statement `chk_exist_obj = chk_exist_obj[0]`, we see that `chk_exist_obj` is now a single list item. What are you trying to arrange?

From the trackback printout, `arrange_ips()` calls `ip_list_read()` which fails on line `548` as it tries to access a list entry that does not exist.